# Как использовать IF для расчетом между ячейками данных в csv?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

Каким образом можно провести операции в файле csv между столбцами или строками? С удовольствием почитал бы инструкцию и желательно используя простые способы. Пример что нужно сделать:

1. Сложить из столбца Open значение первой строки со второй и записать результат в новый столбец. Затем вторая с третьей и т.п.
2. Сложить из столбца Open значение первой строки со пятой и записать результат в новый столбец. Затем вторая с шествой и т.п.
3. Сложить из столбца Open значение первой строки со пятой и записать результат в новый столбец. Затем первую с шествой, седьмой и т.п.
4. Если в строке Close значение меньше чем в предыдущей строке столбца Open, то ставим в новый столбец букву А.
5. Если в строке Close значение меньше чем в предыдущей строке столбца Open, то ставим в новый столбец значение Close этой строки прибавляя к ней значение из ячейки Open, которое находится на 2 ячейки ниже.
6. Если в строке Close значение меньше чем в предыдущей строке и больше чем в следующей, то записываем в новый столбец значение из ячейки на 5 строк ниже, суммируя с ячейкой на 3 строки выше из столбца Close.

Примеры немножко образные, чтобы разобраться, как это работает.

```css
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

a = r'C:/Users/II/Downloads/*.csv' 

files = glob.glob(a)

df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['Date'])
```

Данные

```js
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2011-04-15,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,300.0,10.263332
2011-04-18,14.78,14.85,14.24,14.24,1800.0,9.743323
2011-04-19,14.85,14.85,14.85,14.85,400.0,10.160698
2011-04-20,15.49,15.49,14.71,14.71,1100.0,10.064907
2011-04-21,15.14,15.56,14.81,15.01,18600.0,10.270174
2011-04-25,15.01,15.01,15.01,15.01,0.0,10.270174
2011-04-26,15.01,15.01,15.01,15.01,0.0,10.270174
2011-04-27,15.0,15.63,15.0,15.63,3300.0,10.694392
2011-04-28,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,500.0,10.263332
2011-04-29,15.18,15.18,14.99,14.99,1700.0,10.256489
2011-05-02,15.0,15.05,14.99,14.99,2000.0,10.256489
2011-05-03,15.05,15.05,14.99,14.99,700.0,10.256489
2011-05-04,14.76,14.76,14.2,14.2,1700.0,9.715954
```

Пример с df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[11,12,13,14], 'c':[21,22,23,24]})

1. Сложить из "a" 1 и 2 и записать результат в новый столбец. Затем 2 и 3 и т.п.
2. Сложить из столбца "a" 1 и 3 и записать результат в новый столбец. Затем 2 и 4 и т.п.
3. Сложить из столбца "а" значение 1 и 3 и записать результат в новый столбец. Затем 1 и 4 и т.п.
4. Если в строке "с" значение 22 меньше чем в предыдущей "а" 1, то ставим в новый столбец букву А.
5. Если в строке "с" значение 22 меньше чем в предыдущей "а" 1, то ставим в новый столбец значение "с" 22 прибавляя к ней значение из ячейки "а", которое находится на 2 позиции ниже - цифра 4.
6. Если в строке "с" значение 22 меньше чем в предыдущей строке и больше чем в следующей, 21>22<23, то записываем в новый столбец значение 24 (на  две строки ниже), суммируя с ячейкой на одну строки выше - 21.

Comment: Предлагаю вам сделать другой пример - например `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[11,12,13], 'c':[21,22,23]})` и на основании данного DF показать что вы хотите получить, т.е. указать в ответе результирующие DataFrame's для каждого вопроса

Comment: да, иначе не совсем понятно

Comment: я имел в виду показать __значения__. Например: в первом вопросе в новом столбце ожидаются такие значения: `[3,5,7,???]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полезные ссылки на документацию и примеры:

- [Bollean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- [.shift()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method
- [Working with missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html)
- [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   a   b   c
0  1  11  21
1  2  12  22
2  3  13  23
3  4  14  24
```

Решения:

1.

```
In [17]: df['n1'] = df['a'].shift(-1) + df['a']

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   a   b   c   n1
0  1  11  21  3.0
1  2  12  22  5.0
2  3  13  23  7.0
3  4  14  24  NaN

In [19]: df['n1'] = df['a'].shift(-1).fillna(0) + df['a']

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   a   b   c   n1
0  1  11  21  3.0
1  2  12  22  5.0
2  3  13  23  7.0
3  4  14  24  4.0
```

2.

```
In [22]: df['n2'] = df['a'].shift(-2) + df['a']

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   a   b   c   n1   n2
0  1  11  21  3.0  4.0
1  2  12  22  5.0  6.0
2  3  13  23  7.0  NaN
3  4  14  24  4.0  NaN
```

3.

```
In [25]: df['n3'] = df.loc[0, 'a'] + df['a'].shift(-2)

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   a   b   c   n1   n2   n3
0  1  11  21  3.0  4.0  4.0
1  2  12  22  5.0  6.0  5.0
2  3  13  23  7.0  NaN  NaN
3  4  14  24  4.0  NaN  NaN
```

4. непонятно, укажите в вопросе ожидаемый результат
5. непонятно, укажите в вопросе ожидаемый результат
6. непонятно, укажите в вопросе ожидаемый результат